# Android Studio not starting. RaspBerry Pi

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, raspberry-pi4

Android Studio isnt starting. When i type ./studio.sh There is this Error Message:

```
OpenJDK Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
```

IDE is being shut down

OS: Raspbian/ Raspberry Pi 4

Comment: No, that warning won't stop Android Studio starting. Do you have an ~/.AndroidStudio/system/log folder, or similar? I'd guess it's RAM though: how much do you have? How much is free?

Comment: But it might also be the Java version if you have one much newer than Android Studio is expecting, and there's some incompatibility e.g. a breaking framework class change. Which Java version do you have please?

Comment: @Rupi I have 4GB RAM and Java 11

Comment: a reboot fixed it (KUbuntu on a ThinkPad)